# Scoll a div within a div seamlessly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a seemingly unique requirement. My website is one long vertical page split into equal sized divs (I'm calling 'screens'), which exactly fit the user's screen size.

As you scroll down the page, one of the screens contains a div taller than the screen size, so I would like to scroll this inner div once you reach the point that the said screen is in position. When you have scrolled to the bottom of this inner div then the scrolling of the rest of the page needs to continue, all the while having the next screen slightly visible below so the user can choose to skip to it.

I have tried using basic CSS (overflow-y etc) but there are a few problems with this. If you just scroll down using the middle mouse wheel or the scroll bar it just goes straight past the screen, as you would expect. I need to almost 'hijack' the scroll event and when scrolling down the page, transfer the scrolling to the inner div rather than the window.

The second and more easily solved issue with using CSS is the double scrollbar.

Example HTML:

```
<div id="Content">

    <div id="Screen1" class="Screen">
        Just the opening screen
    </div>

    <div id="Screen2" class="Screen">
        <div>
            LONG CONTENT GOES HERE - ie, longer than the screen
            I need to scroll this instead of scrolling to the next screen
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="Tab">JUMP TO NEXT SCREEN</a>
    </div>

    <div id="Screen3" class="Screen">
        <a href="#" class="Tab">JUMP TO NEXT SCREEN</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope I have explained my requirement, but please let me know if you need any more information.

Comment: You do explained well, and yes we need more info, providing some code for exemple. Thanks

Comment: If you have your pointer over the inner div and scroll, that should scroll the inner div first, until it reached the end of the inner container, in which it'll scroll the next outer div. You can move your pointer out of the inner div to scroll the outer container. All browsers that I know of behave in this way.

Comment: Yes this the basic HTML way, but I would like a more dynamic way of doing it. I don't want to rely on the user doing this, I want to give them all the same experience regardless of how they choose to scroll.

Comment: You could use the locking feature of [SuperScrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/) or [Waypoints](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints) to do this.

Comment: @Mathletics Perfect, thanks. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as so.